# Esri Navigator for Android

Tags: android, arcgis-navigator

I want to build a navigation system for IPhone and Android.
Does Esri Navigator support Android?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows a total lack of research effort.

Answer (score 2):

According to Esri's [Navigator for ArcGIS](http://doc.arcgis.com/en/navigator/#systemRequirements) page it requires iOS Version 8 or later, so no it doesn't currently support Android.

[Further down the page](http://doc.arcgis.com/en/navigator/#sneakPeek) however it indicates that an Android version is in development.